# Why SSSD fails to start?

Tags: sssd

Hi cross compile and installed SSSD for ARM architecture.
Since on my board I don't have `systemctl`, `service` or other similar programs, I try to start SSSD itself with the command:

```
sssd start -c /etc/sssd/sssd.conf -d=0x0100
```

The output I obtain is something like the following:

```
#sssd start -c /etc/sssd/sssd.conf -d=0x0100   
[sssd] [confdb_init_db] (0x0100): LDIF file to import: 
dn: cn=config
version: 2

dn: cn=sssd,cn=config
cn: sssd
domains: LDAP_DOMAIN
enable_files_domain: true
config_file_version: 2
services: nss, pam

dn: cn=LDAP_DOMAIN,cn=domain,cn=config
cn: LDAP_DOMAIN
enumerate: true
id_provider: ldap
auth_provider: ldap
ldap_uri: ldap://<server_IP>
ldap_search_base: dc=ldap,dc=local
cache_credentials: true
ldap_default_bind_dn: uid=test,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=ldap,dc=local
ldap_default_authtok_type: password
ldap_default_authtok: mypsw


[sssd] [server_setup] (0x1f7c0): Becoming a daemon.
```

As far as I can see, there aren't evident critical or error messages, but I am not able to to a simple lookup of a user (e.g. `id user`)  that resides on the remote server.
My `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` configuration file is the following:

```
[sssd]
domains = LDAP_DOMAIN
enable_files_domain = true
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/LDAP_DOMAIN]
enumerate = true
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
  
ldap_uri = ldap://<server_IP>
ldap_search_base = dc=ldap,dc=local

cache_credentials = true

ldap_default_bind_dn = uid=test,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=ldap,dc=local
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = userpsw
```

Can anyone provide some steps in order to understand why sssd is not working?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you used something like `pgrep -a sssd` to see if the `sssd` process is running or not? Does your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file include `sss` on the `passwd:` and `group:` lines? Do you have the `libnss_sss.so.*` library installed?

Comment: @telcoM thanks, yes, I added sss to the nsswitch.conf, and the libnss_sss.so.* are present.
Adding a more debugging level, I see the following error while running the sssd command:
[sssd] [sbus_server_socket_listen] (0x0020): Unable to start a D-Bus server at unix:path=/home/andrea/Scrivania/Autenticazione/FAA-Zynq-feb22/sssd-master-2/sssd-master/install-1/var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-monitor [org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.BadAddress]: Socket name too long
I cannot understand how change/modify that path. Any suggestion please?